# I/O Handle in Sound Blaster, what is? (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, audio, x86, wav, x86-16

I'm trying to put a song playing on a game me and my group made. From a video from Leo Ono, I downloaded a Development Kit for Sound Blaster Series PDF, and found some drivers on a Github repository he also mentioned. On that video, he showed how to do it for MIDI play. But now that I've that working, I was trying to see if I could figure out how to use the WAV driver. But when trying to understand how to play the file, it asked for a `wIOHandle`. I believe I might not know others, but also I don't know where to read about them. If anyone could tell me where I could read about these things in the picture or tell me what they are I'd be grateful.
The picture is one that has 2 (maybe 3, I'm not sure because I can't try anything not knowing the others) that I don't know:

[image]

```
Parameters:
- wIOHandle
    Digitized sound I/O handle.
- dw32BitAddx
    Specifies the 32-bit linear address of the DMA buffer. Currently, the buffer must be sited entirely 
    within the lowest 1MB of memory.
- w2KBHalfBufferSize
    The DMA buffer size, in units of 2KB per half-buffer.
```

It's also mentioned in other functions a wFileHandle, but I'd say that one is the one we get after using INT 21h / Ah = 3Dh - this is correct, right?

I'm using the driver CTWDSK.DRV (there was CTWMEM.DRV too, but I think DSK is reading from the disk itself where I would have the file as I do, and MEM I'm not sure what memory that is, maybe RAM?). Also, this is for 16-bit 8086 programming, running on DOSBox, being assembled with MASM, if that helps.

By the way, if I'm working on 16-bit, how am I supposed to use a 32-bit address? Some DX:AX address? A new segment? (I just learned we can make new segments) Unless the driver is for 32-bit CPUs? Sorry if these are all basic questions. I'm learning Assembly. Maybe this is actually too advanced and I didn't know?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Link to the PDF (which is a DOCX, actually) I mentioned (if I can post it for some reason - copyright? I hope not -, just tell me and I'll delete the link immediately): https://github.com/leonardo-ono/Assembly8086PlayMidiUsingCtmidiDriverSB16/blob/master/LRMNL.docx

Comment: Look through the pdf, presumably there is a function that returns your handle. Could be something with `open` or `initialize`. As for the address, that is a physical address. In real mode you can calculate as per the normal rule of segment*16+offset.

Comment: What address would it be? Probably not a random one, right? Hope this is not a too weird question. Also, about the the handle, I used the search function on Adobe Acrobat and looked at all "Return Value" instances. They're all errors. Not handles. I've linked the PDF (actually is a DOCX) in the question now in case you (or anyone else) would want to have a look on it.

Comment: Maybe a better version of the first question. Would I have to create a new segment with a label and give them both to the function? Or I need to put "db" somewhere or something? I'm also a bit confused because of the "lowest 1MB". I'm not sure what they mean with that - offset 0 inside the segment? Including having to put Para (Paragraph) on the segment definition for the pointer to being for sure at offset 0?

Comment: Since you are in real mode, all your memory (except a little HMA) is under 1MB so no problem with that. As for the handle, the docs say _"CTWAV_OUTPUTHANDLES The DWORD is assigned the number of input or output handles supported by the driver. Invoke all input or output functions with a handle in the range zero to one less than this returned value."_ so apparently you don't need a function to initialize. You can pass 0 if you have just one i/o.

Comment: @Jester possibly one last thing. I can't check if I understood the things you said correctly because this gives me various weird error codes. Would you know why error codes are 2X and 3X (decimal) and not 1, 2, 4, 8 or 10 (hexadecimal) as some functions say? I can't debug this decently, so I'm using a function which prints unsigned numbers (I've seen it working various times). And those errors come up. Would you have any idea why? In any case, already thank you for the help.

Comment: And/or, if you'd know (I'm sorry if I'm being annoying, just trying to understand/learn this things), what are the constants talked about on the PDF? They're not declared anywhere on the PDF, nor can I call them (or jump to them) on the program, so I'm guessing they're not defined there also? It's said on the PDF I need to do some things first with the constants, but I can't understand where they are. Though, the ctwdGetEnvSettings error code (the 3X which is actually 32) can't have to do with this since it's the first thing to do.

Comment: Do you get the error from the `ctwdSetDMABuffer`? What arguments did you pass?

Comment: Well, I don't get the errors only from that one, but for that one I passed SI = 0 as you said, `mov dx, sb_buffer` (a segment defined with `para`) / `lea ax, sb_buffer_array` (the array is defined as `sb_buffer_array db 65000 dup(0)` to be sure there was enough space) / Cx = 8. Those are the arguments. 8 because I put 16 on `ctwdSetDiskBuffer` and they say at most half. No idea if I just did something stupid without knowing - sorry if that's the case. From there, the error is number 26 decimal. I get from even `ctwdGetEnvSettings` (32 decimal) which is the first one to be called...

Comment: 26 is driver not initialized. Did you call the Init function? Did you pass a correct pointer to the `ctwdGetEnvSettings`?

Comment: Supposedly I did. I did the exact same thing than to play a MIDI file on that part. Copy-pasted. And the MIDI works (even though it says I didn't provide a valid IRQ or something despite having copied the string as they say - but works?). And on `ctwdGetEnvSettings` it gets me error 32 which I have no idea how to get to it. Also, how did you get to know 26 is driver not initialized?

Comment: Listed in the `GetDrvError` section. Midi might work without IRQ, I don't remember.

Comment: But those are DOS error codes. The error on `ctwdGetEnvSettings` is 32. That doesn't exist anywhere. I also noticed they say "bit-or'ed combination", but no combination gives 32 - unless I'm doing it wrong. Also, the MIDI works, even with that error. But WAV doesn't, though with a different error. Both 32 (WAV) and 4 (MIDI) come from `ctwdGetEnvSettings`. But Sound Blaster 16 is configured for IRQ 7 in DOSBox, so it should work, I guess (it does with MIDI, just not with WAV, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong - I can post the code if you'd want and if it doesn't take you much time.

Comment: Or maybe this doesn't belong anymore to my original question and I should post a new one?